# Type.GetType not finding a type by name

Tags: c#, reflection, structuremap

I'm trying to use StructureMap to perform runtime type registration, and I'm having trouble locating types in the referenced assemblies using `Type.GetType()`.  Here is the full code of my test app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Graph;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(r => r.Scan(
                s => {
                    s.AssembliesFromPath(
                        @"c:\Path\To\MyClasses\bin\Debug");
                    s.Convention<MyConvention>();
                }
                                              ));

            ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            foreach (var name in MyConvention.assemblyQualifiedTypenames) {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found for reflection by assembly qualified name: {0}", Type.ReflectionOnlyGetType(name, false, false) != null);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by assembly qualified name: {0}", Type.GetType(name) != null);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by search: {0}",
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.AssemblyQualifiedName == name))
                    .FirstOrDefault() != null
                );
            }
            Type type = null;
            foreach (var name in MyConvention.fullnames) {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by full name: {0}", Type.GetType(name) != null);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by search: {0}",
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.FullName == name))
                    .FirstOrDefault() != null
                );
            }
            foreach (var name in MyConvention.typenames) {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by name: {0}", Type.GetType(name) != null);
                Console.WriteLine("Type found by search: {0}",
                    (type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
                    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name == name))
                    .FirstOrDefault()) != null
                );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);
            Console.WriteLine("Type instance retrieved from StructureMap: {0}", instance != null);
            Console.ReadLine();
            ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave()
                .Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Where(s => s.Contains("Class2")).ToList()
                .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private class MyConvention : IRegistrationConvention {
            public static List<string> typenames = new List<string>();
            public static List<string> fullnames = new List<string>(); 
            public static List<string> assemblyQualifiedTypenames = new List<string>(); 
            public void Process(Type type, Registry registry) {
                if (type.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(o => o.GetType().Name == "MyClassAttribute")) {
                    registry.For(type).Use(type);
                    typenames.Add(type.Name);
                    fullnames.Add(type.FullName);
                    assemblyQualifiedTypenames.Add(type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The test class definitions:

```
namespace MyAttributes {
    public class MyClassAttribute : Attribute { }
}

namespace MyClasses {
    public class MyClass1 { }

    [MyClass]
    public class MyClass2 { }
}
```

The output from running the console app:

```
MyClasses.Class2, MyClasses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Type found for reflection by assembly qualified name: False
Type found by assembly qualified name: False
Type found by search: True
MyClasses.Class2
Type found by full name: False
Type found by search: True
Class2
Type found by name: False
Type found by search: True

Type instance retrieved from StructureMap: True

Class2 (MyClasses.Class2)                60eb30ad-ae50-413d-884f-04743ea3148c
  Configured Instance of MyClasses.Class2, MyClasses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
                                         60eb30ad-ae50-413d-884f-04743ea3148c
  Configured Instance of MyClasses.Class2, MyClasses, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I've done all of the testing based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426752/get-instance-from-structuremap-by-type-name) - am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code. This avoids using Assembly Qualified Name, hence no hardcoding for versioning.

```
const string myClass = "<Namespace.Class>";
const string dllName = "<DllName>,"; //Notice the ','

Type myType = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => a.ToString().StartsWith(dllName)).Select(a => a.GetType(myClass )).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get the type using `Type.GetType(name)`. Therefore .net will try and locate the assembly itself - either in the GAC or the same directory as the executing assembly. Since it is in a different directory, it cannot find it. You can confirm this by copying the executable containing `MyClasses` into the same directory as the console app - then it works.

For similar reasons, it will not be in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` as nothing in the current domain uses `MyClasses`.

You either need to load the assembly returned from `MyConvention.assemblyQualifiedTypenames` and then use `assembly.GetType(name)`, or use the version of `Type.GetType` which allows you to specify your own assembly resolver as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332932.aspx) (which will only work if the class includes the assembly name).

Comment: If you look at the output, you'll see that the class **is** found when I explicitly search `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` for it, with any of the 3 different strings.  `Type.GetType()` is not finding it with any of the 3 different strings.

Comment: I'll try the overload you referenced to see if that allows me to see the types.